# searching an array in vb.net

Tags: mysql, arrays, vb.net

I am creating an array by selecting data from a MySQL database, here is where i create the array:

```
Dim call_costs_data(10000, 5)
While reader.Read()
    counter = counter + 1

    call_costs_data(counter, 1) = reader.GetString(0)
    call_costs_data(counter, 2) = reader.GetString(1)
    call_costs_data(counter, 3) = reader.GetString(2)
    call_costs_data(counter, 4) = reader.GetString(3)
    call_costs_data(counter, 5) = reader.GetString(4)
End While
number = counter
```

i am doing this multiple times with different tables, so when i run my function the data is all in arrays rather than searching the database each time in my loop (inside the function)

i am currently searching the array using a `For` loop like this:

```
For p = 1 To number
    If call_costs_data(p, 1) = "some_value" Then
        'do something here
    End If
Next
```

but because i do this for so many arrays inside my loop and there are so many records to loop through before the correct one is found, its taking a long time.

What is the best way to change this to search the arrays?

Comment: you would either have to sort the array ( O(log n) ) or use a hash function ( O(1) in theory but not guaranteed)

Comment: You might be able to get better performance using the data object.  use a select query with just the columns you need, order it by something ,meaningful, then use a DataView or *maybe* `DataTable.Select` to do look ups.  if you can, load and process one table at a time, rather than all of them ahead of time.

Comment: so your saying its better to use a select query rather than arrays?

Comment: i run a `For` loop 9 times inside my While loop so that would mean running 9 queries instead - would that be better than using the arrays

Comment: You have to run 9 queries anyway to get the data into an array, no? From the tiny bit you show there *might* be several ways to improve.  a) `cost_data` implies numbers, you are converting to string (and need to turn on Option Strict) b) as is, you copy the data to an array, you can query and filter the table so that you dont have to look for data much at all - set the right RowFilter and a DV will have just that row in it.

Comment: i do the 9 queries before the While loop which reads the data in, i thought searching through an array is faster than querying a database. as the data has already been put in the array when the function is initiated so its already loaded all of that data

Comment: databases are designed by very smart people to search for data. why not let the software do that work for you?

Comment: @Jeremy sorry - how do you mean?

Comment: a DataReader is not the only way to get data from the database.  You could load a datatable and use that in place of the array.  No need to copy data to a different container.  Best of all, the data will retain its type rather than be whatever `call_costs_data` ends up being in that code - probably `Object`

Comment: you said "i thought searching through an array is faster than querying a database", however in many cases issuing a SELECT statement with a WHERE clause on a properly indexed database can search for you and be very quick.